# Objective C calculator program

Tags: objective-c

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface calculatorViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import "calculatorViewController.h"

@interface calculatorViewController ()

@end

@implementation calculatorViewController

@synthesize display=_display;
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSString *digit=[sender currentTitle];
    NSLog(@"digit pressed %@", digit);

    UILabel*myDisplay=self.display;
    //[self display] why not just type

    NSString *currentText= myDisplay.text;//[myDisplay text]; why are we not writing current title again?
    nsstring*newText=[currentText stringByAppendingString:digit];
    [myDisplay setText:newText];
```

Hi guys!
I have been trying to learn Objective-C so these questions might be *stupid* for you but tough for me, so please do not down vote my question as I am only trying to learn like you. :)

I have a couple of questions in .m file.

1. `(IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton*)sender` Does `(UIButton *)` mean that it is a type and that `sender` is a pointer simultaneously? Cant we remove the bracket?
2. `NSLog(@"digit pressed %@", digit);`Why does this not work with `*digit`. Doesn't digit only store the address and not the actual value?
3. `UILabel*myDisplay=self.display;` I know `self.display` is a getter but what exactly is `self`When do we use it?
4. `NSString *currentText= myDisplay.text` Why are we writing `.text` and not `currentTitle` like in `NSString *digit=[sender currentTitle];`
5. Lastly I read a lot but could not understand. In one sentence what is the difference between `NSString` and `UILabel`?

Comment: I suggest you start reading a programming tutorial for objective-c which starts from scratch. In a such tutorial which also explains the basics of software development all your questions will be answered.

Comment: Hi @Flovdis I have a bit knowledge of python and I am reading OBJ C for dummies as well but they do not really go into this

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic due to, too many basic questions. I wouldn't really recommend OBJ C for Dummies it's not that good a book, I would probably recommend `"Beginning iOS 7 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK"` and as a more advanced book `"IOS 7 Programming Pushing the Limits"`

Comment: @Popeye I will definitely purchase what you are recommending. I can delete the question if you would like me to.

Comment: No don't delete it, it may get closed but it can still help others. It's just because you have asked a basic questions on one question, normally best to ask a few questions.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. (UIButton*)sender means that the sender is passed in the parameter of the method, and that sender is casted to a UIBUtton object.
2. Because *digit is a pointer to an object, so that will print the memory address of the object
3. You use it if you want to access the variable trough the getter, and not directly the instance variable.
4. Is the same, is just a convention, use . to access properties and space to access methods.
5. NSString represents a string object like "ABC", UILabel is a view that will be displayed in your screen, and which text is a NSString.

I won't go into more details, as SO is not a tutorial page. You'll find all this answers in the first chapter of any CocoaTouch programming book.

Comment: Thank you so much !! Really helped. I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Just one question. What do you mean by you are trying to access through the getter and not directly the instance variable? And for example if i press '5' on calculator *digit should print that. is 5 the address that gets printed with just digit?

Comment: You have 2 ways of accesing the variable, _myVar and self.myVar. In the first one, you are accesing the variable directly, in the second trough the getter.

Answer (score 1):

1. (UIButton *) is a typecast to a UIButton object. If you are sure that the sender is a UIButton you can add the typecast. In that way you can directly access the properties/methos on the UIButton object

2.
As far as I understand digit refers to the string object. And *digit means the first (located at index 0).

3.
self means the class it self i.e. calculatorViewController

4.
text is a property of UILabel component

5.
You cannot display a NSString on the display itself you need a UILabel component. You can set the text property to a NSString object and display it on the screen

regards

Johan